# google vm instance blocked said vm used as crytpo mining

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google said my virtual machine instances had done some crypto mining activities, but my virtual machine just contained a nestJs project and a react project that were used as stocking systems.

I already tried to appeal to Google twice and still got blocked.

I already reviewed the package that I installed, and it doesn't use any libraries for crypto mining, yet the instance is still marked as having mining activities.

Comment: Unfortunately, your instance has been compromised. That means do not trust any data that exists on that instance. Start over and create new resources and restore your data from a backup. Do not recover data from a compromised instance. Instead, delete those resources.

Answer (score 2):

If Google has flagged your virtual machine instances as having crypto-mining activities it is possible your machine has been compromised by an attacker who installed mining software without knowledge.